# Homeomorphism between punctured plane and cylinder

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to prove that the cylinder and the punctured plane are homeomorphic.

I understand that I need to find a function that maps every point in the plane to a point on the cylinder.

I can represent every point on the plane in polar coordinates and now I just need to find a mapping from each point in the plane in R^2 to the cylinder in R^3.

I have found that a solution is $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\log(r))$ which makes sense except I cannot understand why  $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,r)$ would not be a solution. Since $r \in (-\infty,\infty)$, wouldn't this still result in a cylinder?

Comment: [See if you can find something useful here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269712/finding-a-homeomorphism-mathbbr-times-s1-to-mathbbr2-setminus-0-0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you figure out how to map a single "ray from the origin" on the plane to its corresponding "line" on the cylinder, you can extend this to the entire plane by putting $e^{i\theta}$ in front of everything (in other words, repeating that map for each angle, and using it to send each ray to its line).

Here is a gif I made ([originally from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315641/264)) that may help illustrate the map we should think of (I assume that in your problem, we are supposed to consider an infinite cylinder and the entire punctured plane, not a finite cylinder and an annulus, though in fact they are all homeomorphic).

[image]

To be specific, let's say that the cylinder we're looking at is the infinite vertical cylinder of radius $1$:
$$C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\}.$$
The punctured plane is
$$P=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\neq 0\,\text{ or }\,y\neq 0\}.$$
So, let's figure out how to do one ray and one line. Hopefully you agree that the ray
$$r_0=\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>0\}$$
should be sent to the line
$$\ell_0=\{(1,0,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
(roughly speaking, because they are both at an angle of $0^\circ$, when viewed from above).

We need to find a homeomorphism from $r_0$ (which is itself homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) to $\ell_0$ (which is itself homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$). So we just need to find a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

There are many examples, but one good one is the logarithm. Just like how $0$ is the "neutral element" for addition in the real numbers, $1$ is the "neutral element" in multiplication. And in fact, the logarithm is precisely the map $\log:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ that converts multiplication into addition:
$$\log(a\cdot b)=\log(a)+\log(b).$$
You can see that $\log(1)=0$, and that $\log(1),\log(2),\log(4),\log(8),\ldots$ are evenly spaced "additively" in $\mathbb{R}$, just like how $1,2,4,8,\ldots$ are evenly spaced "multiplicatively" in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

[image]

So, we can surmise that in the homeomorphism $f:P\to C$ that we're thinking of, we are going to have $f(r_0)=\ell_0$, and that the formula for how $f$ acts is
$$f(x,0)=(1,0,\log(x)),\;\text{ for all }x>0$$
Can you now modify this to see the formula for the entire map $f$?

(Again, I should say that of course there are infinitely many homeomorphisms from $P$ to $C$, this is just one that's easy to think of / write down.)

Comment: Thank you! I understand why log works. I needed to find a function that takes only positive values(namely r) and maps to $(-\infty, \infty)$, and $\log$ does this nicely. I overlooked the easy fact that $r >0$.